# How do I activate Powertop only when my laptop is running on the battery?

Tags: powertop

I don't want powertop to reduce performance while my laptop is plugged in.

Comment: How are you activating powertop?

Answer (score 0):

Use   [acpi_listen](https://linux.die.net/man/8/acpi_listen)

Terminal -> acpi_listen

Example :
Unplug your power supply and you will see something like this ...

```
ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000 <--- Important
processor LNXCPU:00 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:01 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:02 00000081 00000000
processor LNXCPU:03 00000081 00000000
battery PNP0C0A:00 00000080 00000001
```

Under /etc/acpi/events create a file :

sudo nano /etc/acpi/events/switch-to-battery.sh

```
event=ac_adapter ACPI0003:00 00000080 00000000
action=powertop --auto-tune
```

Make ist executable:

chmod u+x /etc/acpi/events/switch-to-battery.sh